# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API with minimal footprint

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, .net-core-publishsinglefile

I want to create an ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API with a minimal footprint in terms of published size and RAM consumption. CPU consumption doesn't seem to be that much of a problem, and the number of calls in my use case are very low.

For a test, I tried the *ASP.NET Core Empty* template. I then applied the following flags in my `csproj` file:

```xml
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

This gets me an executable that is ~46 MB, and when I run it from `cmd` I find a new process that consumes ~19 MB.

My question: In ASP.NET 2.X, there was this meta package `AspNetCore.App` that included everything one usually needs. But for my embedded system, this is *usually* a little coarse. Now, in 3.0, I see neither the meta package listed in `.csproj` nor any individual packages. Is there still a way to control *exactly* what packages get referenced and which do not?

Given the `PublishTrimmed` option: Does it make sense to care about which packages get referenced at all? Or is anything that is not used stripped out anyway?

**Update**

To make it clearer, the embedded system will run a Yocto-based Linux distribution, some C-based codes to communicate with the underlying measuring hardware and the ASP.NET Web API to communicate with the outside world, nothing else! Once the LTS version of ASP.NET Core 3.1 is released, our system may be shipped to customers and run for 5-10 years without any updates—at least assuming there is no need for critical security fixes. Usually the device is only reachable on the LAN.

Comment: This creates a self-contained package. If you publish a framework-dependent executable (`--self-contained false`)you'll probably get 1/10th of that, if not less. As the name says, the appropriate runtime must be installed on the server. RAM consumption depends on what your code does, not the executable size

Comment: Thanks for you comment but I don't see what this helps. A non-self-contained app would need the runtime globally installed. Since my Api is the only .NET Core app on my device I guess I end up with more than I have now because I loose the trimming.

Comment: You have to decide what you want (and clarify it in the question). Small executable or small container/total footprint? How and how often do you intent to upgrade the runtime/app itself? 3.0 is a "current" version. The LTS version will be 3.1 which comes in November.

Comment: If you need to deploy *two* .NET Core applications, using self-contained executables will take 92MB while installing the runtime will result in far smaller deployments

Comment: Ok, tried to make it clearer.